# How can I send Form Select value?

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I have made this form to email script, when I receive email, I got all of the fields except `select`. It works fine without select option.

Kindly tell me what is wrong. Or if I am not using the select option correctly.

```
<form class="form-signin cform" method="post" action="send-sales.php" id="cform" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="form-input">
        <label>First name<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" required name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <label>Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <label>Interested Product<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <select required="required" id="product">
            <option value="eerp">Educational ERP</option>
            <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
            <option value="erp">ERP</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <label>Message<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <textarea required name="message" cols="40" rows="7" id="messageTxt" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-large main-bg" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" class="btn btn-large" value="Reset" id="reset">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php
    $email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";/* CHANGE THIS WITH YOUR OWN EMAIL ADDRESS */
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $product = $_POST["product"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $text = "Sender's Name: $name<br>
             Sender's Email: $email<br>
             Sender's Email: $phone<br>
             Sender's Interested Product: $product <br>
             Sender's Message: $message";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: <$email>" . "\r\n";
    mail($email_to, "Sales Message from Website", $text, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Give it a name, then get it in `$_POST` like you do any other input. All inputs need a name-attribute if you want to send them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name missing from your select tag

give name to select

```
<select required="required" id="product" name="product">
```

just it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a name attribute on your select tag

`<select name="products">`